Allowing user to change Parameter in PowerBI Desktop
I have the following source in Power BI:
let
    DateText = Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateParam), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    BaseURL = "http://myurl/date/" & DateText,

I want to allow the user to change the value of DateParam directly from the report.
I have tried multiple options without success.
One of the options I tried was creating a table with date values and attempting to bind it to the parameter. However, I couldn't find the Bind To Parameter option in the modeling view.
Could you please let me know if you have a solution or any workaround for this issue?
Thank you in advance.
